# VBA - For Each loop ends after first item

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a fairly simple macro that will add the received date to the subject line of an email. 
I've compiled the code below and it works for a single e-mail. However, it appears the `For Each` loop ends after the first email, and I'm at a total loss on how to solve this. I've tried changing the the `PickFolder` line with an `ActiveExplorer.Selection` line - exactly the same problem.

```
    Sub SelectedMailItemsSubjectWithDate()
        Dim objMainFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim MObj As Outlook.MailItem


        Set objMainFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

            For Each MObj In objMainFolder.Items
                'Adds the date to the subject
                MObj.Subject = Format(MObj.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD") & " - " & MObj.Subject
            Next MObj
    End Sub
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this? I would be much obliged!

The reason I'm trying to add the date is that we will need to archive thousands of e-mail in the .msg format, in an online storage that doesn't show anything except the subject line of the file.

Comment: When the code is running and paused, try executing `?objMainFolder.Items.Count` in the immediate window (`ctrl+g`) to see how many items is picked up. If only 1, then that is the error, if more than 1, then something else causes it to stop.

Comment: Thanks - I've run your code in the immediate window and it lists 4 (which is the actual number of mails in my test folder) .

Comment: You can try putting some error handling code, may be possible it is throwing some error. This link may help. http://analystcave.com/vba-proper-vba-error-handling/

Comment: Are you getting an error message or something? A *type mismatch* by any chance?

Comment: No error whatsoever, it appears the script simply stops running. On further investigation it appears that this particular script only works on the actively selected e-mail in the folder that I select in the pickfolder line. I'm baffled!

Comment: Are your getting any dialog box, while running this code. Is it possible some dialog box is stopping this? Like you are using PickFolder, this may lead to this behavior. May be you want to be more speficic, which folder email you are going to read, like all email from inbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a sec, how do you know only one item is processed? Are you stepping through your code and see that the loop exits prematurely? Or that only one item is modified? In the latter case you need to save the item:

```
MObj.Subject = Format(MObj.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD") & " - " & MObj.Subject
MObj.Save
```

Comment: This did it - thank you so much! This is going to save me so much time, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Declare `MObj`  as a generic `Object` rather than `Outlook.MailItem` - you can have other items in a folder, such as `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem`, etc.

Comment: Upvoted for the truth of it, but unless OP is facing a *type mismatch* error, this isn't fixing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Mat's Mug - if the exceptions are ignored, the loop can bail out on the second item thus giving the impression that only one item is processed.